# Feasibility of application of Boyle's law in the case of varying number of moles

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases, gas-phase-chemistry

While reading up on ideal gases and the Boyle's law, I encountered a question in my textbook wherein a balloon was being filled with helium (assumed to be ideal) till it was just about to burst. The pressure and volume coordinates at some intermittent time of the process, and the limiting pressure at the bursting point were provided, and the volume at that point was asked. The book solved it by applying Boyle's law at the two $\ce{P,V}$ coordinates. Also, it was given that this entire activity is being carried out at room temperature. 
So, if the amount of gas in the system is constantly changing, then can we apply Boyle's law in this case? If not, then can somebody provide a solution?

Comment: It may help to quote the actual question from this textbook.

Comment: A balloon is filled with Hydrogen at room temperature.It will burst if pressure exceeds 0.2 bar.Of at 1 bar pressure, the gas occupies 2.27L volume, up to what volume can balloon be expanded.

Comment: As per the textbook , They simply applied P1V1=P2V2 as per Boyles law

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volume change inside a balloon upon decreasing the the outer pressure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48394/volume-change-inside-a-balloon-upon-decreasing-the-the-outer-pressure)

Comment: You are correct that using Boyle's Law wouldn't work for the problem as described. I assume the author of the question had some thought of what they wanted the question to be about, but didn't make sure the real situation made since. There is an early question that addresses this same problem, so I marked as a duplicate. @PrakharPandey